# Keep Getting this.callInitHooks error (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I'm trying to add markers and a search bar to my leaflet choropleth map. However, I keep running into an error that tells me: **Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function**. It comes from my leaflet.js file, and am unsure how to fix it. Most of my error seems to come from the leaflet links I've copied into my body before my script, or because of me trying to add a search bar or markets onto my map. I pasted my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>How to make a choropleth map with Leaflet.js</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-search.css" />
    
    <script src="censustracts.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #map{
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

         .info {
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.info h4 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    color: #777;
}

.legend {
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555;
}
.legend i {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></map>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script> 
    <script src="leaflet-search.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">


var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'OSM'})
    .addTo(map);

L.geoJson(statesData).addTo(map);


    L.geoJson(statesData).addTo(map);

    function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
               d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
               d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
               d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
               d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
               d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
               d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                          '#FFEDA0';
    }

    function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}


L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style}).addTo(map);


///Functionality

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
    info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();
}



function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}

geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

//Add info
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map);

//Add Legend
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
        labels = [];

    // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
            grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
    }

    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);



///Bind Popups

var data = [
        {"loc":[32,-86], "title":"aquamarine"},
        {"loc":[41.575730,13.002411], "title":"black"},
        {"loc":[41.807149,13.162994], "title":"blue"},
        {"loc":[41.507149,13.172994], "title":"chocolate"},
        {"loc":[41.847149,14.132994], "title":"coral"},
        {"loc":[41.219190,13.062145], "title":"cyan"},
        {"loc":[41.344190,13.242145], "title":"darkblue"},  
        {"loc":[41.679190,13.122145], "title":"Darkred"},
        {"loc":[41.329190,13.192145], "title":"Darkgray"},
        {"loc":[41.379290,13.122545], "title":"dodgerblue"},
        {"loc":[41.409190,13.362145], "title":"gray"},
        {"loc":[41.794008,12.583884], "title":"green"}, 
        {"loc":[41.805008,12.982884], "title":"greenyellow"},
        {"loc":[41.536175,13.273590], "title":"red"},
        {"loc":[41.516175,13.373590], "title":"rosybrown"},
        {"loc":[41.506175,13.273590], "title":"royalblue"},
        {"loc":[41.836175,13.673590], "title":"salmon"},
        {"loc":[41.796175,13.570590], "title":"seagreen"},
        {"loc":[41.436175,13.573590], "title":"seashell"},
        {"loc":[41.336175,13.973590], "title":"silver"},
        {"loc":[41.236175,13.273590], "title":"skyblue"},
        {"loc":[41.546175,13.473590], "title":"yellow"},
        {"loc":[41.239190,13.032145], "title":"white"}
    ];

    var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements

    map.addLayer(markersLayer);

    var controlSearch = L.Control.Search({
        position:'topright',        
        layer: markersLayer,
        initial: false,
        zoom: 12,
        marker: false
    });

    map.addControl( controlSearch );


    for(i in data) {
        var title = data[i].title,  //value searched
            loc = data[i].loc,      //position found
            marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title} );//se property searched
        marker.bindPopup('title: '+ title );
        markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `new` with lowercase function:

```
 marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title} );
```

Use `new L.LatLng(loc)` or `L.latLng(loc)` without `new`